# Macro for filling-out forms in Google Drive does not send any information

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro to send info directly to Google Drive but it is not sending any information. I already have the form created on the drive and also the spreadsheet.

Here is the code I have:

```
Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()
Dim Resultado As String
Dim url As String, DatoMetodoPost As String

Dim winHttpsolicitud As Object
Set winHttpsolicitud = CreateObject("winHttp.winHttpRequest.5.1")

url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdY7sC6vt7ZK9NlhVHyyBRqSRS13eyUBPIds9lEOovyN2JzUg/formResponse"

DatoMetodoPost = "entry.644094283 =" & Cells(3, 2).Value & "&entry.2079263836 =" & Cells(3, 3).Value & "&entry.1246329708 =" & Cells(3, 3).Value

winHttpsolicitud.Open "Post", url, False
winHttpsolicitud.setRequestHeader "Cotent-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpsolicitud.send (DatoMetodoPost)

Resultado = winHttpsolicitud.responseText

End Sub
```

Comment: "Cotent-Type" should be "Content-Type"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the correction. But I did the change, still didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub enviar_informacion()
On Error GoTo errores
Dim Resultado As String
Dim url As String, DatoMetodoPost As String
Dim winHttpSolicitud As Object
Set winHttpSolicitud = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

i = Hoja1.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Ultima fila para planos

url = "URL FORM HERE/formResponse"

DatoMetodoPost = _
"entry.137216655=" & Cells(i, 3).Value & _
"&entry.1993437904=" & Cells(i, 4).Value & _
"&entry.1730967372=" & Cells(i, 5).Value & _
"&entry.533831839=" & Cells(i, 6).Value & _
"&entry.1953147463=" & Cells(i, 7).Value & _
"&entry.77576574=" & Cells(i, 8).Value

winHttpSolicitud.Open "POST", url, False
winHttpSolicitud.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x- 
www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpSolicitud.Send (DatoMetodoPost)

Resultado = winHttpSolicitud.responseText

MsgBox "Sus datos fueron guardados con exito", vbInformation, 
"Jefferson Montoya"
```

Exit Sub

errores:
MsgBox "Ha ocurrido un error al momento de guardar la informacion", vbCritical, "Cheques"

End Sub